# How can I check if CSV records are the same as in SQLite?

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, csv

I have CSV file with 10mil. records and I need to check if all the values in the file are the same as in SQL DB. I don't need to return true or false, I also need to know how many does not match (if some) and which one are not the same probably by some selection.

My question is just what is the fastest way, it might be done manually so far (as I have seen there is an option to import csv to sqlite), but later I need to do it programmatically.

Should I create new DB from csv and then check it with the other db?

I guess it should be done by some inner/outer joins etc. Any idea?

I've got pretty simple idea but it is not working:

```
select Email_Address from eloqua_export where Email_Address != (select Email_Address   
from eloqua_export_duplicate)
```

It returns me all the email addresses even though they are the same in both tables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!=` compares a single value, so it takes only the first row of the subquery.

To compare with a all values in a set, use IN:

```sql
select Email_Address
from eloqua_export
where Email_Address not in (select Email_Address
                            from eloqua_export_duplicate);
select Email_Address
from eloqua_export_duplicate
where Email_Address not in (select Email_Address
                            from eloqua_export);
```

Comment: You have my +1 for pretty good answer, unfortunately EXCEPT is better in this case.

Comment: But what if email address is not unique? How should I proceed? but I have one column unique how should I change it? I know I extend the question but would you be so kind?

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer I needed:

```
SELECT * FROM eloqua_export
except
SELECT * FROM eloqua_export_duplicate
```

It selects every record from one table which is not in second table. That means, if both tables are the same, an empty table will be returned.

Comment: EXCEPT cannot use any indexes.

Comment: If you explain it to me I will mark your answer as right, why should not I use except? Thanks

Comment: If you have an index on the `Email_Address` column, (NOT) IN can use this index to speed up lookups. EXCEPT always creates a temporary sorted table for the first query, then deletes all rows from the second query.